# Request payload size exceeds the limit: 4194304 bytes

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, random-forest, google-earth-engine

I am getting this error, as I am trying to export to drive a classified image, which is rather large, since it includes the whole area of New South Wales in Australia. The manual says that in this case it will be exported in many smaller files, but this is not the case for me. Please take a look on my code, and help me figure out how can I eventually export it, either in 1 image or more.
Thanks in advance.

```
//SPECIFY AND MODIFY THE AREA OF INTEREST 

var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterBounds(geometry);

var S2 = S2.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 'less_than', 5);

            
var S2 = S2.filterDate('2019-12-14','2020-01-16');

print(S2.size());

            
var S2_image = S2.first();

var S2_clipped_collection = S2.map(function (S2_image){
  return S2_image.clip(geometry);
});
print(S2_clipped_collection);


var S2_image = S2_image.select('B2');

var S2_clipped_collection = S2_clipped_collection
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());

print(S2_clipped_collection);

var S2_clipped_collection = S2_clipped_collection.select( 'B2_mean', 'B3_mean', 'B4_mean', 'B5_mean', 'B6_mean', 'B7_mean', 'B8_mean', 'B11_mean','B12_mean');

Map.addLayer(S2_clipped_collection, {bands:['B4_mean', 'B3_mean', 'B2_mean'], min:500, max:2800}, "222");


var classnames = burned.merge(unburned);

var bands = ['B2_mean', 'B3_mean', 'B4_mean', 'B5_mean', 'B6_mean', 'B7_mean', 'B8_mean', 'B11_mean','B12_mean'];

var training = S2_clipped_collection.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: classnames,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 10
});

print(training);

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'landcover',
  inputProperties: bands
});

//Run the classification
var classified = S2_clipped_collection.select(bands).classify(classifier);

//Display classification
Map.centerObject(classnames, 11);
Map.addLayer(classified,
{min: 0, max: 3, palette: ['red', 'blue', 'green','yellow']},
'classification');


Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified, 
  description: 'description',
  region: geometry, 
  scale: 10, 
  crs: 'EPSG:25832',
  maxPixels: 1e19
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple suggestion here, your scale is currently set to 10 m, which is incredibly small. Unless you absolutely need the high resolution I would suggest increasing it to 100 m at the very least. If it still won't export, either reduce the size of your geometry or increase the scale further.